# Free/delete strtok_r pointer before processing complete string?

Tags: c++, stack-trace, free, strtok, delete-operator

When trying to delete/free character ptr without being processed completely by `strtok_r`, its giving me stack trace error.

I know that one cannot free/delete a `strtok_r` char ptr in a regular way, without completing the whole strings separation process by `strtok_r` func.

Can anyone tell me how to free a char ptr, when its under process by `strtok_r`?

```
 char *data = new char[temp->size()+1];//temp is of type string
 copy(temp->begin(),temp->end(),data);
 data[temp->size()]='\0';

 count = 0;

while(pointData != NULL)
{
if(count == 0)
pointData = strtok_r(data,":",&data);

else
pointData = strtok_r(NULL,":",&data);

if(count == 5)//some condition to free data
delete[] data;// this produces stack trace error

cout<<pointdata<<endl;

count++;
}
```

Comment: Could you please post some actual code? It's just painful trying to guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because strtok_r is advancing "data" as it goes, which means that it is no longer pointing at the address of the allocation; you need to keep a "freedata" pointer or the like around:

```
char *data, *freedata;

freedata = data = new char[temp->size()+1];

// do yer stuffz here

delete[] freedata;
```

Answer (score 2):

The context passed to `strtok_r` in the third argument should be a different pointer to the string you want to separate. Try:

```
char *context;

....
pointData = strtok_r(data,":",&context);

else
pointData = strtok_r(NULL,":",&context);
```

I don't believe you need to initialise it before you pass it in.

Answer (score 0):

The only pointers you may **ever** pass to `free` are those obtained by `malloc`, or those obtained from functions which are specified to return a pointer to memory "as if" obtained by `malloc`. `strtok_r` does not return a pointer to a string "as if obtained by `malloc`", so you may not call `free` on it. If you read the specification for this function, it returns a pointer to character in your input string, which has been potentially modified to clobber a separator with a null terminator.