# Want to free my pointer token after strtok

Tags: c, char, free, strtok

I have extracted the "meaning" part of my code (and also replace some line to simplify it).

I have 2 dynamic pointers, one for the current line (extracted from a file) and a second for the current token.
Following this question, [Free/delete strtok_r pointer before processing complete string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226653/free-delete-strtok-r-pointer-before-processing-complete-string)
I wrote this :

```
int main(void) {
    int n = 455;  
    char *tok2, *freetok2;
    char *line, *freeline;

    line = freeline = malloc(n*sizeof(*line));
    tok2 = freetok2 = malloc(n*sizeof(*tok2));

    /* content of the file) */
    const char* file_reading =  "coucou/gniagnia/puet/";

    /* reading from the file */
    strcpy(line, file_reading);

    strtok(line, "/");
    /* get the second token of the line */
    tok2 = strtok(NULL, "/");

    fprintf(stdout, "%s \n", tok2); // print gniagnia
    fprintf(stdout, "%s \n", line); // print coucou

    /* free error */
    //free(tok2);

    /* worked, but maybe don't free "everything ?" */
    //free(line);

    free(freetok2);
    free(freeline);

    return 0;
}
```

But at the end, I'm not sure of what is correct or not, and I find this solution not so elegant (because of using 2 "save variables".

Is that correct ? Is there some ways to improve it ? 
Thanks

Edit: changed my code for this, (and it will handle all the lines of the file)

```
include <unistd.h>
include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char *tok2; 
    char *line; 

    /* content of the file) */
    const char* file_reading =  "coucou/gniagnia/puet/";
    const char* file_reading2 =  "blabla/dadada/";

    /* reading from the file */
    line = strdup(file_reading);

    strtok(line, "/");
    /* get the second token of the line */
    tok2 = strtok(NULL, "/");

    printf("%s \n", tok2);
    printf("%s \n", line);

    /* reading from the file */
    line = strdup(file_reading2);

    strtok(line, "/");
    /* get the second token of the line */
    tok2 = strtok(NULL, "/");

    printf("%s \n", tok2);
    printf("%s \n", line);

    free(line);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not actually using the memory pointed by `freetok2`, you don't need to `malloc` anything, thus you don't need the `freetok2` variable.

Saying `free(line)` or `free(freeline)` **is the same** in your code so you don't need the `freeline` at all.

Another problem is this: `malloc(n*sizeof(*line));`. You might as well be saying: `malloc(n);` because `sizeof(char)` is always 1. But best of all would be:

```
line = malloc(strlen(file_reading) + 1);
strcpy(line, file_reading);
```

Comment: You say I don't need the freetok2 variable, but if I try to free(tok2); I will get a heap error (free invalid pointer).
Otherwise, I didn't put the +1 for the ntc, because I used already a int (don't know in advance the size of my string, I just know that it will be less than 300 char).

Comment: @roro You don't need to `free(tok2)`. You only need to `free(line)`.

Comment: I was expecting something like that, but how is it possible ? I wanted to follow the strong "rules" free everything you allocate..

Comment: @roro `line = freeline = malloc()` is only ONE allocation, not two, so you will only need to free one of them. Moreover, you don't need to allocate 455 chars to `line` in order to assign file_reading to it. What if file_reading is longer than 455 characters? `strdup(file_reading)` is much better, that automatically allocates exactly enough memory.

Comment: @roro *free everything you allocate* but you didn't allocate `tok2`, did you ?

Comment: @MrLister `strdup` is great but you need to be aware it's not standard.

Comment: @cnicutar Oops. In that case, `malloc(strlen(file_reading)+1)`. As long as you don't allocate a fixed amount of memory and hope it will be enough for the input.

Comment: @MrLister it's ok for the line freeline pointers, I wanted to be sure that I free all the char*.
The problem was more about the tok2 pointer, (that I allocate in my example, because I will assigned the result of the strtok function). 
But you say that I didn't need to allocate it. Which means I could use an unallocate pointer or that strtok will allocate it for me.

Comment: @roro `tok2` is just a pointer to a location somewhere in the line.

Answer (score 2):

The code should be modified as follows:

```
int main(void) {
    int n = 455;  
    char *tok2;
    char *line;

    line = malloc(n*sizeof(*line));

    /* content of the file) */
    const char* file_reading =  "coucou/gniagnia/puet/";

    /* reading from the file */
    strcpy(line, file_reading);

    strtok(line, "/");
    /* get the second token of the line */
    tok2 = strtok(NULL, "/");

    fprintf(stdout, "%s \n", tok2); // print gniagnia
    fprintf(stdout, "%s \n", line); // print coucou

    free(line);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok so I simply don't need to allocate tok2. I find it weird because it sounds like using a char* without allocating it.